# Excel VBA to insert a row from user input and autifill down

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to insert a row across multiple sheets based off of a user input row number and autofill the inserted row.

```
    Sub AddNewRep()

    Dim SelRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    SelRow = Selection.Row
    On Error GoTo nonNumeric
    j = InputBox("ENTER ROW TO INSERT NEW REP", "ADD REP")
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo NumericEntry

nonNumeric:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox ("Please try again with a number.")
    Exit Sub

NumericEntry:
    For i = 1 To 9
        Sheets(i).Select
        Rows(j).Insert
        Sheets(i).Select
        Rows(j - 1).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows("(j - 1):(j)"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        On Error Resume Next
            Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    Sheets(1).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
End Sub
```

I am getting a "Run-Time error '13':  Type Mismatch" on the line:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows("(j - 1):(j)"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Anyone have any ideals as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By encasing your variables in quotation marks, they're being interpreted as `String`s. You only need quotation marks around the `:`.

Change

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows("(j - 1):(j)"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

to:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rows(j - 1 & ":" & j), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

EDIT: I'm also pretty sure you're going to need some column references here, for example:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & j - 1 & ":G" & j), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: This works; however, now I am experiencing a problem where 4 specific cells, all of which have formulas that reference other sheets are not properly autofilling. They autofill; however the row reference is not changing- it is still referencing the previous row number.  For example: I input row 25 as the row to insert, the rows insert and all the other formulas autofill correctly with the new row number except for these 4 cells.  The formula in these cells are as follows:  `=SUM(SUNDAY!AL24,MONDAY!AL24,TUESDAY!AL24,WEDNESDAY!AL24,THURSDAY!AL24,FRIDAY!AL24,SATURDAY!AL24)`

Comment: [https://satco2-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mikestapp_satco2_onmicrosoft_com/EWUni03e52hCgJRETCiTDvcBft8Ur69Ym3fwRzknJ2iHiw?e=grOrkL] Here is a link to the Excel file.  The macro button to run this specific macro is on the "Setup" tab/sheet.  The four cells that are not properly auto-filling are on the "Summary" sheet columns B, C, D, and G.  All other columns are auto-filling correctly.

Comment: Oh.. I should note... when I manually insert a new row and manually fill down the formulas on the "Summary" sheet that is exhibiting the above issue, the formula fills down correctly.

Comment: @MikeyB. So I looked at your workbook but had trouble working on it because sheet 1 was corrupted (receiving run-time error 32809 on it which means it's corrupt), but it doesn't look like your updated code for `AddRep` was in it. Also, nothing is "autofilling" down, it's just that when you insert a new row all the other formulas adjust for that insertion. You also have the issue of a different number of columns for each worksheet, which complicates the whole looping through worksheets and dragging down formulas. You may need to use another solution.

Comment: Yes, I realized about 10 minutes ago I had put the wrong version in the shared link. I have updated it here: [https://satco2-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mikestapp_satco2_onmicrosoft_com/EZqXYO9kPmVPkfEXfyvXO8YB9Qg1cytikws9rSdrx7bnIQ?e=UTx1OK]  I will look at the corruption issue- it may be causing other underlying issues. And I think I may have a workaround by rearranging where things are placed and using 2 different macros. One to add the new rep and then one to populate it on the schedule sheets, which could work around the varying number of columns.  Thanks for all your help!